# Выбор всех элементов, содержащих конкретное значение

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть таблица типа такой

```
<table>
    <tr> <td>1</td> <td>0</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>1</td> <td>3</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Задача задать стиль для всех ячеек, которые содержат 0. Ячейки с другими значениями не трогать.

Какие есть способы такое сделать? В `css` я что-то не нашел подходящих селекторов

Comment: Задать стиль ячейкам, текст которых только "0"? Или же тех, в тексте которых содержится "0"?

Comment: Тех, которые состоят только из нуля

Comment: @Андрей Курулёв, если добавить аттрибут, то можно сделать и без js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну в `css` это не сделать. Можно через `js`

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

cells.forEach(c => {
    if (c.innerText === '0') {
        c.classList.add('hightlight');
    }
});
```

```css
.hightlight {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr> <td>1</td> <td>0</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>1</td> <td>3</td> </tr>
</table>
```